# Esri ArcGIS shapefile to CAD - CAD file returns empty?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, autocad

I'm using ArcGIS 10.6.1, and I need to transform a points shapefile into a CAD file for AutoCAD.

I used the "to CAD" transformation tool in ArcMap and everything seemed to go smoothly, but when I tried to open the CAD file in TrueView, nothing came up. It wasn't a visibility issue because the layer was visible in TrueView.

What is the problem? I should also caveat that it's my first time doing this transformation. I have plenty of experience doing conversions the other way round though.

I used a coordinate system that I've created; this custom coordinate system is what I use on the CAD files the same architects give me to line up my data with their true geographic location instead of CAD's local coordinate system

The point file's attributes are: (1) latitude (2) longitude (3) name - nothing else! How does a shapefile's attributes affect how it gets transformed into a CAD file?